# how to auto execute a terminal process after my mac is turned on

Tags: linux, terminal, cron

i can do it with my crontab

```
* * * * * ./something.sh
```

but it is going to start the script every single minute,

so what is a better way to make it just start once?

I want the computer automatically run the script once after i turn on the power, and keep running the script. until i turn off my computer. thanks

Comment: The title says Mac, but the tags say Linux. What operating system are you using?

Comment: On OS X you should use `launchd`, on Linux you can put a script in the appropriate `/etc/rc#.d` directory, or use `inittab` or `systemd` depending on your distribution.